# Order of a product in an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian group and has two element $a$ and $b$, such that $\circ(a)=m$ and $\circ(b)=n$ and $lcm(m,n)\neq m,n$. Is it true that $\circ(ab)=lcm(m,n)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have try many things, but none of them work. Any idea?

Comment: I have shown $\frac{mn}{gcd(m,n)^2} \mid \circ(ab)$.

Comment: I have also shown that $G$ has an element of order $lcm(m,n)$. But could not show that it is $ab$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is not true. In $\mathbb{Z}/30 \mathbb{Z}$, $o(3) = 10$ and $o(5) = 6$, but lcm$(6,10) = 30$ and $o(3+5) = o(8) = 15$.

Answer (score 5):

But it is true that if $\operatorname{ord}(a)=m$, $\operatorname{ord}(b)=n$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(m, n)=1$ then $\operatorname{ord}(ab)=mn=\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$.

In general, one can say the following:

> **Proposition.** If $G$ is a finite abelian group, and $\operatorname{ord}(a)=m$, and $\operatorname{ord}(b)=n$. Then
>   $$\frac{mn}{\gcd(m, n)^2}\mid \operatorname{ord}(ab) \mid
>  \frac{mn}{\gcd(m, n)}=\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)$$

It looks like you have shown $\frac{mn}{\gcd(m, n)^2}\mid \operatorname{ord}(ab)$ as you indicated in the comments. Very nice!

For the proof of the above fact, see the article

Dieter Jungnickel, *On the Order of a Product in a Finite Abelian Group*. Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 69, No. 1 (Feb., 1996), pp. 53-57

Comment: Apparently the PDF is freely available at http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Dieter_Jungnickel20395.pdf.

Comment: Nice find! I was using my university's access to JSTOR, so it didn't occur to me that the article could be found elsewhere freely. Thanks a lot!